# Typescript Angular - Recieving Type is missing following properties from type

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So I'm trying to setup a model and keep getting the mentioned area. Screenshots attached show my syntax - I assumed it was an error from not passing the 'name' , 'amount' but in my array I give two new values with both of those.

EDIT - Can' post images so code below.

```
  ingredients: Ingredient = [
new Ingredient ('Apples', 5),
new Ingredient ('Tomatos', 10)];
```

- 

```
export class Ingredient{

constructor(public name: string, public amount: number){ }}
```

Comment: you need to declare the variable as an array: `ingredients: Ingredient[] = [....]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're declaring it "ingredients" variable should be an ingredient and not an array/list of ingredients.

So:

```
const ingredient: Ingredient = new Ingredient ('Apples', 5)
```

or

```
const ingredients: Ingredient[] = [
  new Ingredient ('Apples', 5),
  new Ingredient ('Tomatos', 10)
];
```

To specify an array type you can also use:

```
const ingredients: Array<Ingredient> = [...]
```